# cd ~ works in one terminal session but not another (no error reported)

Tags: cd-command

I have two PuTTy sessions open to the same host.  One one `cd ~` gets me back to my home dir fine and on another one it doesn't -- stays in the same dir.

I have never seen something like this happen.

Any idea why this might be happening?

OS:  SunOS 5.10

Comment: what shell are you using? Also, dump both environments, ie `set > env_goodwindow` ; set > env_badwindow` and diff them. Same for `stty` settings. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, `cd` alone takes you to your home directory. No need for the `~`

Comment: cd alone doesn't work either ... :(

Comment: Does this always happen each time you open two ssh connections to the host, or did it happen just once?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've changed or unset your $HOME environment variable in one of the ssh sessions.

$HOME is the default arg for the `cd` built-in, at least for all the sh-like shells that I have installed on my system (incl. dash, bash, ksh, and zsh).

They all have something like this in their man page (from dash):

```
 HOME   The home directory of the current user; the default argument for
        the cd builtin command.  The value of this variable is also used
        when performing tilde expansion.
```

Comment: `csh` and `tcsh` use `$home` (lowercase).